# MVVMCross Community SQLite-Net Plugin - Can not open database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

I´m trying to open a database file (foo.db) on Windows Phone 8.1. While using the SQLite-Net Plugin I´m getting following SQLiteException: Could not open database file: foo.db (CannotOpen).

Here is the code:

```
public Db(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
{
    try
    {
        const string fileName = "foo.db";
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        using(this.connection = factory.Create(Path.Combine(folder.Path, fileName)))
        {
            //Do SOME STUFF
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //SQLiteException: Could not open database file: foo.db (CannotOpen).
    }

}
```

I already verified the path to the file. If I remove the Community Plugin and use SQLite-net, no exception occurs.

Where's the mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit the question to say what the exception is? And is this a WindowsPhone Xaml 8.1 or a WindowsPhone Silverlight 8.1 project?

Comment: It is a "SQLiteException: Could not open database file: foo.db (CannotOpen)." and it is been thrown at factory.Create(). It is a Windows Phone 8.1 Xaml project

Comment: I wasn't even aware that there was a Jupiter Xaml branch of that project - what version are you using - the Windows Store one? I guess you might be hitting some path combination issues - e.g. in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/blob/0d16aff5c14ad6617d0a86e34225bd06155b1731/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite/BaseClasses.cs#L952 - you could try using the `CreateEx(options)` method and supplying the base path in the options

Comment: I´m using MvvmCross.Community.Plugin.Sqlite.3.1.1 wp8 branch. The same exception occurs, if I´m using the CreateEx method, but I´m not sure if I supply the correct base path - which should it be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but that's how I've dealt with that issue.

I've created the ISQLiteConnection in my PlatformSpecific project and registrated it as a type to the IOC:

```
Mvx.RegisterType<ISQLiteConnection>(() => new SQLiteConnection(fullPathtoDbFile));
```

Then, in my core (PCL) project I am resolving it:

```
public ISQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
    if (_con == null)
    {
        _con = Mvx.Resolve<ISQLiteConnection>(); ;
    }
    return _con;
}
```

- ISQLiteConnection is part of Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite namespace.